# how to get hashmap values depends on key

Tags: java, android, hashmap

i have this hashmap with string and arraylis:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> devNameType = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
public void kimenetPV(String name){
        //létrehozom a nevet
                String devName = name;

                //létrehozom a kimeneteket tartalmazó arraylistet
                ArrayList<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();

                // 2. hozzáadaom az elemeket
                outputs.add("EM A");
                outputs.add("EM B");
                outputs.add("AOUT1");
                outputs.add("AOUT2");               

                devNameType.put(devName, outputs);

                Iterator iter = devNameType.entrySet().iterator();

                //kilistázom az elemeket
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
                    System.out.println(mEntry.getKey() + " : " + mEntry.getValue());
                }
    }
```

how can i print all the values?
Sorry for the begginer question i'm using the hashmaps for first time.

Comment: use outputs.get("position").  position is the index of arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the key:value pairs as this:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> iter = devNameType.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, List<String>> next = iter.next();
    List<String> value = next.getValue();
    System.out.println("key = " + next.getKey());
    System.out.println("values : ");
    for (String str : value) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: how should i define the iterator?

Comment: how should i define the iterator?

Comment: added the iterator definition

Answer (score 1):

```
for (List<String> value : devNameType.values()) {
    ... do something with this value
}
```

For key/value:

```
for (String key: devNameType.keySet()) {
    List<String> values = devNameType.get(key);
    ... do something with the name and values
}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values() and
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()

Comment: with this how can i know which key has this values?

Comment: okay but i need in htat way : if(key == 'something') print the values of 'something'

Comment: Can you not then do a check against the 'key' value?

Answer (score 0):

With hashMap.values() you get a Collection of all values:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#values()