# Map with multi values

Tags: java, dictionary

I basically want 2 values on 1 map if possible or something equivalent. I want to store this info

> ```
> Map<K,V1,V2> sample = new HasMap<K,V1,V2>
> (Key - caller) = 26
> (value 1 - callee) = 55
> (value 2 - seconds) = 550
> sample(26,55,550)
> ```

the only other way i see how i can do this is

> Map(k, arraylist(v2))

having the position in the arraylist as V1 but this will take forever to search if i would want to find what callers have called a specific callee.

i have also read this [HashMap with multiple values under the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956844/hashmap-with-multiple-values-under-the-same-key) but i do not understand how to do this.

Comment: The accepted answer of the question you've mentioned contains all you need. Read it carefully, and ask if you don't understand something *specific*.

Comment: You can also use Google guava's MultiMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create a wrapper object (it was given in the discussion link that you have in your question) to hold values `v1 and v2`:

```
class ValueWrapper {
V1Type v1;
V2Type v2;
...
}
```

Now you can map your keys to the instances of this wrapper:

```
Map<K,ValueWrapper> sample = new HashMap<K,ValueWrapper>();
sample.put(new K(), new ValueWrapper());
```

Comment: i just didnt understand how to implement it from that link but it is clearer now after your explanation. thank you

Comment: if you could. how would i iterate over the valuewrapper class because k = 26 can have many valuewrapper classes.

Comment: this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495155/how-to-get-hashmap-values-depends-on-key/19495337#19495337

Answer (score 2):

Create a bean for your value like below

```
  class Value {
    VariableType val1;
    VariableType val2;
    ...
    }
```

Then we can create a map like below

```
Map<K,Value> valueSample = new HashMap<K,Value>();
valueSample .put(new K(), new Value());
```

We need to set the value in Value calss by setter or constructor

Answer (score 0):

If all values are `<V1, V2>` you can use `Entry` as value:

```
Map<K,Map.Entry<V1,V2>> sample = new HasMap<K,Map.Entry<V1,V2>>();
```

Create `Entry<V1,V2>` and put it with the relevant key.

Another solution (and even better one) is to create your own value class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
  Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
  List<Integer> list =new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(55);
  list.add(550);
  //Adding value to the map
  map.put(26, list);

  //getting value from map
  List<Integer> values = map.get(26);
```